# Invalid umlaut characters when starting tomcat as a service

Tags: linux, tomcat, service, charset

my problem is that the umlaut characters in an application pages (WAR) are not properly rendered when Tomcat is started as a service, but when I start the server manually it all looks good. I've checked the system's encoding (en_US.UTF-8) and it should working properly in both cases.

/etc/init.d/tomcat7

```
#!/bin/bash  
# description: Tomcat Start Stop Restart  
# processname: tomcat  
# chkconfig: 234 20 80  
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-openjdk  
export JAVA_HOME  
PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH  
export PATH  
CATALINA_HOME=/opt/tomcat  

case $1 in  
start)  
sh $CATALINA_HOME/bin/startup.sh  
;;   
stop)     
sh $CATALINA_HOME/bin/shutdown.sh  
;;   
restart)  
sh $CATALINA_HOME/bin/shutdown.sh  
sh $CATALINA_HOME/bin/startup.sh  
;;   
esac      
exit 0
```

Can you please help me out with this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution source here: [Utf-8 in tomcat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1663571/how-to-set-utf8-lang-on-tomcat-java-running-on-mac-os-10-5-8)

Add the property `-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8` to the CATALINA_OPTS variable or set it at runtime.